# Sending a string from C# via serial

Tags: c#, arduino

I am trying to send a string of data through a serial port from the computer to an [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega) board. The string of data consists of some letters for identifiers and two values. The one value is between 0 and 240 (so may be a two digit value or three at times) and the second value is a number between -45 and + 45. I have managed to write the code in C# to send the string, and it shown below.

```
    private void goButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            return;
        command = 43;
        outBuffer += "E" + command1 + "F";
        outBuffer += "G" + command2 + "H";
        // Therefore send through serial port a string in the following format:
        // E<command1>FG<command2>H
        // Where <command1> will be an int value between 0 - 240, and
        // <command2> will be be a value between -45 and + 45
        serialPort1.Write(outBuffer);
        outBuffer = "";
    }
```

Now I am having an issue with extracting the values from the string, when it is received on the Arduino board. I have written some code, which seems to display the string correctly, but I have not been able to find what I am doing wrong, or how to actually filter/extract the two values, and have them stored in two separate variables. The Arduino code I currently have is:

```
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
      char inData;
      String inDataString;
      inData = Serial.read();
      inDataString = inData;
      // Shows the string of E<command1>FG<command2>H
      Serial.print(inDataString);
  }
```

How do I get the code on the Arduino to be correct, so that I can get two values sent from the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know arduino but you could do something like:

```
int start = inDataString.indexOf('E')
int end = inDataString.indexOf('F')
char str_char[end - start];
inDataString.substring(start, end).toCharArray(str_char, sizeof(str_char));
int my_integer_data = atoi(str_char);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you send the string you could add a carriage return/linefeed after each command. Like:

```
outBuffer = string.Format("E{1}F{0}G{2}H{0}", Environment.NewLine, command1, command2);
```

After you read it in, you then know that each command exists on its own line so you can split it:

```
string[] commands = inDataString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this sort of thing on Arduino is to use the TextFinder library (http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/TextFinder). For example:

```
#include <TextFinder.h>

TextFinder finder(Serial);

void setup() 
{ 
  Serial.begin(9600);
} 

void loop()
{
  finder.find("E");
  long command1 = finder.getValue();
  finder.find("FG");
  long command2 = finder.getValue();
  finder.find("H");

  // Do something with command1 and command 2
}
```